# How to make Amazon Polly speak and also show text when using Amazon Lex

Tags: python, amazon-lex, amazon-polly

So I am stuck at a confusing situation here. I am building an Amazon Lex Bot and when having Amazon Polly give the final confirmation in audio format it only gives the audio output but the text does not show up Lex console.

For example in my python code this a final confirmation piece:

```
if outputDialogMode == 'Text':

    return close(
        session_attributes,
        'Fulfilled',
        {
            'contentType': 'PlainText',
            'content': 'Your reservation has been confirmed from"+str(start_time)+" to "+str(end_time)+". Your Booking ID is " + str(booking_id)
        }
    )
elif outputDialogMode == 'Voice':
    return close(
        session_attributes,
        'Fulfilled',
        {
            'contentType': 'SSML',
            'content': '<speak>Your reservation has been confirmed from"+str(start_time)+" to "+str(end_time)+". Your Booking ID is " + str(booking_id) +'</speak>'

        }
    )
```

Now when I want the Lex to output the `content` in audio format(`outputDialogMode == 'Voice'`) then it only speaks it and does not show the text as well on the console. Is there a way to get it to speak and display the text at the same time?

**Note**: The above code is just a section in my whole code where the output message is being sent.

Answer (score 0):

The text response is returned in the `message` field of the HTTP response.

If you are only interested in the text for output for logging / debugging purposes you can [log the result](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-logging.html) and view it in [CloudWatch](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/)